# Hidden advantages to cooked input?

Tags: c, unix, input

I generally use raw input when writing unix-based programs because I like to use press-key-X to do something menus. In other words the interface says some thing like (Press O to open a new file, Press L to list files, Press D to delete the current file, etc). The user doesn't have to press Enter, they just press the one key.

However, I realize that there are some advantages to using the cooked mode, mostly being able to use built in line editing functionality.

I am about to write a whole new raft of code. Is there any specific reason of which I may not be aware why I should shift to a cooked input mode?

Comment: You may like raw/single char mode, but not so many programs use it, so it may confuse some users. But, okay. But, if user does select `O`, they _will_ expect cooked mode to be able to edit/backspace over the filename they're entering. So, you have to flip back and forth anyway. Overall, unless you're doing your own equivalent of the line editing capabilities ... Also, what about user wanting to cut-n-paste filename from another window?

Comment: IMO, You should write your such that you can do it _either_ way [dynamically]. And, this could depend on the context of _what_ you're prompting the user for. And, this could be selected by the user in a config file. That is, _don't_ hard code policy choices into the code itself. Read them in from the config file [or environment]. You could create an API: `askmenu`, `asknumber`, `askstring`, `askyesno`, `asklist`, etc. Then, 90% of the code doesn't care _how_ it's done and you can change it in _one_ place.

Comment: If your programme is not complicated, consider making it non-interactive, passing any input in `argv`. This will make it simple and allow piping and redirection to work like the user expects.